# How to use SignalR and Push notification correctly?

Tags: push-notification, signalr, onesignal

I and my team making a project using **ASP.Net** as back-end, **Html 5** and **iOS** as Front-end.

My service has a chat function, which users can chat with each others. It is implemented by using SignalR.

We've implemented successfully that function, but finally, we've realized that SignalR only actives when the application is opened. When the application isn't, users cannot receive any information from service.

Next step, we're thinking about OneSignal (Push notification third-party service), the implementation wasn't so complicated and we succeeded sending/receiving push notification.

The problem we're facing with now is :

- **When the application opens, how can we handle the information send from both Signalr and OneSignal correctly ? We don't want to receive push notification when app opens, but we do when app doesn't.**

Can anyone help us please ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to track connected/disconnected users at the server side. 
If a user is connected, then send a signalr message. If the user is not connected, then send a push notification.

That said, it´s not easy to track user connections/disconnections with SignalR, because there´s is a delay from when a client stops (ie: closing the app, network failure, etc) to when the server really thinks that client has disconnected. It could be arround 20 seconds if I´m correct. This happens because SignalR tries to reconect for 20 seconds using the same ConnectionId before it gives up.

**Another possible solution**:

Send every single message by both signalr and push notification.
Set a uid property on each message payload (generated on the server).
The client shows the message and then adds that uid to a local database.
When the client gets another message with the same uid (either way from push notification or Signalr), it will be discarded.

I´ve done this in a chat application and it works pretty well. The only problem is that you will waste push notifications when the app is connected, but push notification services are cheap... and I´m pretty sure that SignalR messages will arrive a lot faster than push notifications.

Comment: Actually OneSignal service is free, therefore, I don't care about pricing much. The only thing I'm wondering is the performance of server because server should send the push notification & signalr message concurrently.

Comment: If you send hundreds or thousands of messages per minute you could be right. This is something to be tested. But if you plan to have such a huge workload I would suggest to implement a distributed architecture and a backpane.